# Run in Java external .jar application like .exe

Tags: java, process

I have written an application in Java. Now I would like to run from my application another program as like `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.cmd");` but  the application I would like to run needs to be a runable Jar file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just in case you see some odd behaviour with this - take a look at this link: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute .jar application using:

```
java -jar application.jar
```

in some cases you need to specify classpath using `-cp` flag and class that contains main function.

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: `-jar` option ignore classpath specified by `-cp`